# UVIews Proportions when zooming UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

in my app i have `UIImageView` inside `UIScrollview` which i can zoom in and out with no problem.
The user is able to add `UIViews` on that image by Touch events.
now on dragging the image there is no problem.. the `UIViews` stays in the right position (x,y).
but when zooming the image the `UIViews` "floating" on the screen and without saving their proportions.

can someone help me please (code will be great) how can i save the `UIViews` positions on zooming?
I added a [short movie to demonstrate](http://youtu.be/A1cj_TMoJao) the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to have a container `UIView` that you put the `UIImageView` and the placable `UIView`s inside and then return the container `UIView` for

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

iOS then does all the work for you!

Answer (score 0):

When you add this view don't add it simply to `scrollivew`'s `view`. Add it to the view that you are returning in 
`- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method.

Also, when you are adding new view you should set its `autoresizingMask`.

Not sure exactly what kind of autoresizing you want. You can start with:

```
newWiew.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | ViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```